# how can I save the layout of my open apps on osx?

Tags: macos, applescript

I'd like to save the position and size of my open apps and restore them later (after restart).

I found an applescript that does this with finder windows only:
http://hubionmac.com/wordpress/2008/09/finder-fenster-position-und-layout-speichern/
(german) Maybe I could adept it, but I can't believe there's no application for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature included in the upcoming version of Mac OS X, Lion:

> ### Resume
>
> Now apps you close will reopen right where you left off, so you never have to start from scratch again. And when you install software updates, you no longer need to save your work, close your apps, and spend valuable time setting everything up again. With Resume, you can restart your Mac and return to what you were doing — with all your apps in the exact places you left them.

Comment: Sadly, this works only for one display. However, when switching between the MBP built-in display and an external display, the position of the apps is not saved per-display, so you have to manually rearrange them every time.

Comment: @FranciPenov Even if you don't disconnect/reconnect displays in between?

Comment: As long as your display configuration is not changed, things work just fine. however, the moment you change your display configuration, all bets are off. (Sadly... Still trying to find a solution for this :-))

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html).

It has a way to save [display sets](http://www.madrau.com/functions/desktop/desktop.html)....which sounds close to what you are asking for.

Comment: thanks. as you say it looks like it should do the job.. 

still I can't get it to work in that way: 
I created 2 display sets (with different resolutions) and activated the save all windows option but end up with the windows scattered all over the place, no closed apps relaunched and even the desktop icons not where they used to be.. :(

I didn't read the manual yet though, just trying to figure out how it works. will do that now. will post again if I find enlightenment there.

Comment: alright: after rebooting it works as intended.
yet it only saves position of icons and windows. it doesn't launch any closed apps - which would be the killer feature for me. (it's able to change to a specific setting when you launch an app though)

it says it's possible to call it from applescript so maybe (no experience there) I can write an applescript script that launches the apps I'd like to have in a display set and then calls the appropriate display set in SwitchResX..

Comment: from the author:
"No, SwitchResX doesn't launch any application; it saves and restores positions of windows & icons on Spaces and on all displays, once the apps are launched. But it doesn't launch them.
You may be able to get things done with using Applescript to launch the application and bind the script to the Display Set, but I suspect that you'll end in a timing issue (the script would launch the apps, and then position their windows, but the applications wouldn't be finished launching when their windows would be restored)."